# Yii CSqlDataProvider custom limit

Tags: php, sql, yii

Is there a way to limit the CSqlDataProvider? When i force the totalItemCount to 3 for example the result is not taken into consideration.

```
$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_user')->queryScalar();
$sql='SELECT * FROM tbl_user';
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
  'totalItemCount'=>3,    
  'pagination'=>array(
    'pageSize'=>10,
   ),
));
```

When i try to limit the query LIMIT 3 and comment totalItemCount line, i receive:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: ... LIMIT 3 LIMIT 10
```

It appears that whatever i do the sql is appended with LIMIT 10.

Comment: Did you already solve it?

Comment: Yes, try my answer or set pagination to false then set limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are using CSqlDataProvider, You can limit your total items in your sql.
As Yii's official document wrote:

> Like other data providers, CSqlDataProvider also supports sorting and pagination. It does so by modifying the given sql statement with "ORDER BY" and "LIMIT" clauses. You may configure the sort and pagination properties to customize sorting and pagination behaviors.

[CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider)

So you can easily do it by changing your sql like below:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM tbl_user LIMIT 3';
```

Comment: Your solution gives: CDbCommand failed to execu tehe SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: ... LIMIT 3 LIMIT 10

Comment: You have syntax error, check your sql.As it says You have two limit in your sql. Or remove 'totalItemCount'=>3

Comment: If i remove the Limit 3 the query runs but returns 10 results. Yes i removed 'totalItemCount' line.

Comment: Did you remove 'totalItemCount'=>3  ?

Comment: You need to set `pagination` to `false` to disable it. Then set `limit` as in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add **;** at the end of the sql statement, in this way the cpagination is not adding the default LIMIT 10 clause.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user LIMIT 3;';
```